# Why won't Nvidia GeForce 7300 LE work with GeForce GT 430 on Win7 anymore?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card

I have the 2 mentioned video cards and I am trying to use them both together. I have downloaded and installed the latest windows 7 64bit drivers for the GT 430 and restarted. Win7 shows that both devices are working properly and I can get both outputs working on the GT 430, but the 7300 LE is not playing ball. It shows up correctly everywhere, even the display properties recognises it and when i plug a monitor in. I have tried different monitors, different motherboard ports, different cables. Nothing works, but nothing seems to say that it shouldn't work. Screen resolution is within the monitors capabilities.

It was working at one point, but I had to disconnect my computer for a move.

Do I need a different driver that works with both or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uninstall the driver for both cards.  then remove one card.  reboot and install the latest drivers.  shutdown and install the other card.  boot and install the latest drivers.  If it still doesnt work, repeat the process, but switch the first card removed.